# HTTPPOST Android to Server

Tags: php, android, database, http-post

I'm working on a program that sends data to a server. The server is receiving my data, but only the last bit of it. Here's my Android code:

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> j2 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
j2.add("drink_name", "rootbeer")
j2.add("drink_name", "pepsi")

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("kubie.dyndns-home.com/R2Bar2/getingredients.php");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(j2));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

But it's only adding the last entry (pepsi) to the database.
Here's my php:

```
 <?php 
$handle = mysql_connect('localhost','root','xxxx'); 
if($handle==false) 
{ 
die('No database connection'); 
} 

$result = mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE 'available_ingredients'");

$db=mysql_select_db('r2bar2'); 
$query='INSERT INTO available_ingredients (drink_name) VALUES ("'.$_POST["drink_name"].'")'; 
$result=mysql_query($query); 
?>
```

Comment: `ArrayList<NameValuePair>` It's called Name -> Value pair not Name -> Value*s* pair. One name, one value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
j2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("drink_name[]", "rootbeer"));
j2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("drink_name[]", "pepsi"));
```

what you're putting in your entity is a List of NameValuePair -- so each thing you add should be a NameValuePair, and the BasicNameValuePair is one of those

in the php

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST["drink_name"] as $drink_name) {
    $query=...
    $result=...
}
?>
```

but a note of caution -- make sure you call `mysql_real_escape_string` on your inputs to guard against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: right, php wants brackets in the name to make an array -- so in your server code, make sure you loop through the array elements of drink_name[]

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the name of the parameters to below (from the Android code):

j2.add("drink_name[]", "rootbeer");
j2.add("drink_name[]", "pepsi");

And in your PHP:

$drink_names = array($_POST['drink_name']);

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You set the same key twice, so when the server receive your request it sees only the last value for drink_name, which is "Pepsi" because it overwrites "rootbeer"

Comment: how would I change this in my PHP?